# Rails: Bootstrap Editing Forms CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, css

I'd like to edit the forms CSS of bootstrap.

```
bootstrap-sass / vendor / assets / stylesheets / bootstrap / _forms.scss
```

I grabbed..

```
textarea,
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="datetime"],
input[type="datetime-local"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="month"],
input[type="time"],
input[type="week"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="color"],
.uneditable-input {
  background-color: $inputBackground;
  border: 1px solid $inputBorder;
  @include box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075));
  @include transition(border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s);

  // Focus state
  &:focus {
    border-color: rgba(82,168,236,.8);
    outline: 0;
    outline: thin dotted \9; /* IE6-9 */
    @include box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6));
  }
}
```

And I attempted to change the rgba values of the focus state.

```
@include box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(200,168,136,.6)
```

But then I get the following error:
**Mixin transition takes 1 argument but 2 were passed.**

I think I'm not allowed to just "override" the box-shadow mixin? But I'm not sure how to fix this issue. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Just a guess but `@include box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(200,168,136,.6)` I would imagine should be written as : `@include box-shadow(0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(200,168,136,.6)` with inset being at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to escape the argument :

```
@include box-shadow(~"inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(200,168,136,.6)")
```

notice the `~` (tilde) and the `"` (quotation marks). This clears confusion about the comma, that less interprets as a seperation between two arguments. See the  "escaping" part on less documentation for more info.

Comment: adding the quotation marks solved the problem without the tilde, in SASS